# Meaning of どく in sentence

Tags: translation, conjugations, parsing

I have a sentence in Haruki Murakami's 海辺のカフカ which reads:

> でも形而上的であり象徴的でありながら、同時にそいつは千の剃刀のようにする**どく**生身を切り裂くんだ。

I understand the first part of the sentence as:

> May it be metaphysical or symbolical, at the same time it's like a thousand razors... ripping apart...

But I don't get the meaning of that どく part. I don't believe it's 毒, as it's written in hiragana.

Comment: I would assume it's not 'ようにする' but instead the adverbial form of the adjective 鋭い.

Comment: Now that you say it, of course. ようにする is just such a common sight, that I've never even considered anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「するど**く**」 is the [連用形]{れんようけい}  (continuative form) of the adjective 「するど**い** / 鋭い」 = "***sharp***".

"sharp" ⇒ "sharply"

It is conjugated into its 連用形 so that it can modify the following verb 「[切]{き}り[裂]{さ}く」 = "to rip up".

One cannot say 「するど**い**切り裂く」.  I feel like I am talking about 連用形 almost everyday here (along with relative clauses).  Wonder how properly those are taught in Japanese-as-a-foreign-language.

Finally, 「[毒]{どく}」("poison") or any other **noun** will not fit in grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

"するどく- 鋭くin 漢字 and かな)" is an inflection of 鋭い. It has nothin to do with "毒," which is a stand-alone noun.

The adjectives such as "するどい - sharp," "辛どい - painful," "くどい - insistent," "悪どい - malicious" inflect into adverbs like, "するどく," "辛どく," "くどく," and "悪どく," and adjectives like "珍しい - unusual,""憎らしい - hateful," "重々しい - heavy, " inflect into adverbs as "珍しく," "憎らしく," and "重々しく."